# Explanation of Ricci Tensor?

Tags: manifolds, tensors, general-relativity

I’ve started studying general relativity, and I’ve been trying to understand the Ricci Tensor. Wikipedia says it involves how a shape changes volume as it travels a geodesic in curved spacetime. This would imply that a Ricci Tensor of zero would mean the shape doesn’t change volume along that geodesic, correct? How does this relate to the Schwarzschild Metric? Wouldn’t that curved spacetime cause a change in volume of a shape along the geodesic, and thus mean the Ricci Tensor would be nonzero?

Comment: Eigenchris has some great videos on diff geo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhDNijOEw0Y

Comment: To lean GR I started with Sean Carroll's book which I still like a lot. The classic by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler has a lot of intuition that has to do with volumes. I don't hink GR can be learned form Wikipedia. The [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#Curvatures) describes a spherically symmetric vacuum solution outside a massive body and has zero Ricci curvature.